# Code coverage of the given code

Tags: java, c#, c++, code-coverage

Why is it that,
If only Unit Testing for function B is done then the coverage of function A is 50%.
Even if we take the values of Function B as (1,2,3)
it would cover the if and else of first function, but why the coverage will still be 50% ?

```
Public int A(int a,int b)
{
if (a%2==0) 
      return a;
else 
    return b;
}


Public int B (int a,int b,int c)
{
 int val=A(a,b);    
 val=A(val,c);
    }
```

Comment: static code analysis can't cross semantic blocks. That is the tool can't detect the code paths through `A` from `B`.

Comment: What if we are doing the code coverage on paper? like dry run.

Comment: what does this have to do with c# or c++?

Comment: Don't spam tags.

Answer (score 0):

You must be doing something wrong. It shows 100% coverage to me. Here is the test (The aim is not to show whether this is a good test or not but to answer your question):

```
[TestMethod]
public void SomeTest()
{
    ClassLibrary1.Class1 csl = new ClassLibrary1.Class1();
    csl.B(1, 2, 3);

    Assert.IsTrue(true);
}
```

And here is the coverage result of that test:

[image]
[image]